# ng-click with a href in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

And I have the following links in my page as following :

```
<li ng-repeat="o in villes | shuffle | limitTo:5"><a href="#" ng-click="searchByVille({{o.codeVille}})">{{o.nomVille}}</a></li>
```

I want when I click on some link to call the `searchByVille` function and to log the parameter I passed to it as following :

```
$scope.search = function(id){
    console.log(id);
  }
```

which doesn't work.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 4):

Omit the `{{}}` in your `ngClick` directive:

```
ng-click="searchByVille(o.codeVille)"
```

`ngClick` already takes an Angular expression - no need for them.

Answer (score 0):

No need to evaluate using {{}}.
Use `data-ng-click="searchByVille(o.codeVille)"`